# Mobile Hotspot from laptop to phone results in not being able to browse on laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, mobile-hotspot

I get internet on my laptop from an ethernet connection and want to share that connection with my phone through the Mobile Hotspot feature on Windows 10. The moment I turn on the hotspot (even before my phone connects), my laptop loses the ability to browse the internet, but it can still ping the websites and they return fine. I can connect to the hotspot from my phone and browse on my phone like normal, but I have to turn off the hotspot entirely to get Chrome to load any webpages, otherwise I just get a "connection reset" error.

This only recently started happening after a Windows update, but I can't find what may have changed.

Comment: If you roll back to prior to the update, does the problem go away? Which update?

Comment: @music2myear Sadly I can't roll back because this computer is mostly managed by my job. I can change some of the networking information around because I'm a local admin, but all the updates are handled by the domain admin.

Comment: Ah, then you should talk to your IT folks about this.